# How to get rid of DBEAVER error icon and highlighting?

Tags: dbeaver

How can I get rid of these error icons and query highlighting?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps below:

1. Right click the error marker and select "Preferences"

   [image: selecting preferences]
2. Expand "SQL Editor" and go to "Code Editor", deselect "Show problem markers" under the "Miscellaneous" category

   [image: Removing error highlighting]

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to show the error highlighting as a debugging aid. Often though, it sticks around long after it's no longer useful. To clear the highlighting in this case you can right-click on "Errors" in the problems dialog and select Delete.

[image: Screenshot of problems dialog]